# How to sort vector elements in R based on values before the delimiter

Tags: r, sorting

I have a vector called `myvec`. I want to sort the values based on numbers before `-`. Any suggestion?

```
myvec <- c("2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq", "2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq", "3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq", 
"3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq", "11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq", "1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq", 
"11-2_16S_S209_R1_001.fastq", "1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq")
```

Also, when I do `sort (myvec)`, I get:

```
[1] "1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq"  "1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq"  "11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq" "11-2_16S_S209_R1_001.fastq"
[5] "2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq"  "2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq"  "3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq"  "3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq"
```

Also tried

```
require('gtools')
mixedsort(myvec)
```

which gives:

```
[1] "1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq"  "1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq"  "2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq"  "2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq" 
[5] "3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq"  "3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq"  "11-2_16S_S209_R1_001.fastq" "11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq"
```

result I want:

```
1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq
1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq
2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq
2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq
3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq
3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq
11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq
11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get the number with `parse_number`, `order` on it

```
myvec[order(readr::parse_number(myvec))]
#[1] "1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq"  "1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq"  
#[3] "2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq"  "2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq" 
#[5] "3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq"  "3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq"
#[7] "11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq" "11-2_16S_S209_R1_001.fastq"
```

---

Or we want to sort based on alphanumeric characters before the first `-`, then extract the substring with `str_extract` (from `stringr`), use `mixedorder` (from `gtools`) to order the vector

```
library(gtools)
library(stringr)
myvec[mixedorder(str_extract(myvec, "^[^-]+"))]
```

Comment: @MAPK If you alpha numeric, then use the second method updated now

Answer (score 2):

We may also use `str_sort` from `stringr`:

```
stringr:::str_sort(myvec, numeric = TRUE)
# [1] "1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq" 
# [2] "1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq" 
# [3] "2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq" 
# [4] "2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq" 
# [5] "3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq" 
# [6] "3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq" 
# [7] "11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq"
# [8] "11-2_16S_S209_R1_001.fastq"
```

Comment: This is simple, yet elegant answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
> myvec[order(as.numeric(sub("(^\\d+).*", "\\1", myvec)))]

[1] "1-1_16S_S197_R1_001.fastq" 
[2] "1-2_16S_S207_R1_001.fastq" 
[3] "2-1_16S_S217_R1_001.fastq" 
[4] "2-2_16S_S226_R1_001.fastq" 
[5] "3-1_16S_S234_R1_001.fastq" 
[6] "3-2_16S_S242_R1_001.fastq" 
[7] "11-1_16S_S199_R1_001.fastq"
[8] "11-2_16S_S209_R1_001.fastq"
```